# How to get multi-select picklist values to display on line indents on visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, picklist, html, multi-select

So I have a multi-select picklist with 4 possible values on it. I would like to have them displayed on the custom visual force page I am making on line indents (li) rather than seperated with a semicolon. I have tried using the substitute function to replace ; with li but it does not appear to work. the substitute function works with br and will show it on a new line, but is there a way to do this that will allow the multi-select to be displayed on bullet points?

Here is the following line of the visualforce page that will display the pick list:

```
<li><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!SUBSTITUTE(Loan_Proposal__c.Standard_Conditions__c,';','<li/>')}"/></li>
```

Comment: Are you using a standard controller or an extension for this?

Comment: @SebastianKessel No I am not, this visualforce page is used to render a record into a PDF to be printed.

Comment: The last parameter in the substitute function should be '<li>' instead of '<li/>'.  See if that does it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried in my de and it works . Just replace with 'Opportunity.Other_Delivery_Locations__c' your custom field :

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="<li>{!SUBSTITUTE(Opportunity.Other_Delivery_Locations__c,';','<li/>')}"/>
```

The output in my screen looks like this

- Australia - AU
- New Zealand - NZ
- United States - US

Answer (score -2):

<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(prod, ';', '
')}" escape="false"/>

You can use sustitute function this will 100% work.

Comment: It appears that OP already knows that using `<br />` would work. I've downvoted this because you haven't answered the question being asked (how to do it and ensure that each value becomes a bullet point).